# OnTouchListener in custom dialog don't work

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, ontouchlistener

I have an an activity called GameViewUI. In this activity I have this method:

```
int DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID = 1;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID:
        Context mContext = this;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.gameoverdialog);
        dialog.setTitle("GAME OVER");

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.pointsGameOverTextView);
        text.setText("Points: " + currentScore);
        // Get buttons and add listeners
        Button playAgainButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        Button goToMainMenuButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.goToMainMenuButton);

        playAgainButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
        goToMainMenuButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

        return dialog;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);

}
```

As well as this one:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.equals((Button) findViewById(R.id.goToMainMenuButton))) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainUI.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
}

}
```

The dialog "pops up" when this code launch:

```
 showDialog(1);
```

The dialog pops up, and I can see the buttons. But they aren't clickable! I can't click them.

What do I do wrong?

I want to click the buttons and get to the other activity.

Please help.

Comment: playAgainButton.setOnTouchListener(this) why don't you use setOnClickListener? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons

Comment: @atzu I have tried that as well. Didn't make a difference at all.

Comment: Try adding android:onClick="onTouch" on the xml to the buttons. Must be clickListeners.

Comment: @atzu Tried that as well. No difference.
The button don't even get "pressed" in when I have added a listener. And nothing happens when I click. It don't enter the onTouch method at all when i debug. I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you can change the logic. As long as it is an Alert Dialog you can try this and declare everything you need in an Alert method. This works for me.

```
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
     private void showAlert(int id){
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID:
                    builder.setMessage("GAME OVER")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Go To Main", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainUI.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);


                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Play Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Custom.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);


                        }
                    });

                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();
                    break;
              }

         }
```

Comment: This actually solves my problem. The LISTENERS are working!! Would still be nice to know why the old method didn't work... so I can learn something from it. ALso now I cant make a custom dialog, but it can work anyway. But thanks a lot for your answer, now I can get on to implementing other features instead of being stuck here.
Great job!

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gameoverdialog);

builder.setView(dialoglayout);